# activerecord reputation system: hide buttons after user vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i'm using Railscast tutorial for implementing the activerecord reputation system: http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system?view=comments

But I can't hide the buttons after the user votes.

I did it like this:

post controller:

```
def accept
  value = params[:type] == "accept" ? 1 : -1  # vote type = accept
  @improvement_action = ImprovementAction.find(params[:id])
  @improvement_action.add_or_update_evaluation(:accepts, value, current_user)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "You accepted the answer!"
end
```

post model:

```
has_reputation :accepts, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

user model:

```
has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source   #accept answer (activerecord reputation-system gem)

has_reputation :accepts, source: {reputation: :accepts, of: :improvement_actions}, aggregated_by: :sum


def voted_for? improvement_action
    evaluations.where(target_type: improvement_action.class, target_id: improvement_action.id).exists?
end
```

And call like this in the view:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action) %>
  VOTED
<% else %>
  NOT VOTED
  <%= link_to "up", accept_improvement_action_path(improvement_action, type: "accept"), method: "post" %>
<% end %>
```

What I am doing wrong? Like this appears always voted

Comment: If user has not voted then show link and `Voted`? Is your if condition inverted?

Comment: yes thats true, i swapped my mistake. but the problem is the same, because even if I vote or not, it appears the same

Comment: I suspect `add_or_update_evaluation(:accepts, value, current_user)` is not working.

Comment: i think u r missing the if condition in your view file here, can you repost it?

Comment: yes it was not showing up, i edited

Comment: so you have changed `<% if current_user && !current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action) %>` to `<% if current_user && current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action) %>` based on your previous comment? because if you didnt the logic is wrong

Comment: how it should be? but either way it appears wrong, with "not" or without

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Readability in a question is very important, and formatting of the information helps make that happen. Please reedit your question and format the code, including correctly indenting it. Correct indentation helps us understand what you're doing, which helps you, and it helps those in the future searching for a similar solution.

Comment: in the original example, it is `<% if current_user && !current_user.voted_for?(haiku) %>
  | <%= link_to "up", vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
  | <%= link_to "down", vote_haiku_path(haiku, type: "down"), method: "post" %>
<% end %>`, the logic is if current_user exist, and if current_user hasn't voted, then show the link

Comment: but in your case, your logic should be if current_user exist and current_user has (not hasn't) voted, show 'VOTED' so it should be `<% if current_user && current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action) %>
        VOTED
      <%     else %>
     NOT VOTED

        <%= link_to "up", accept_improvement_action_path(improvement_action, type: "accept"), method: "post" %>
        <% end %>`

Comment: if you don't change it, you can never see the voting links, because your logic is, if current_user exist and current_user hasn't voted, show `VOTED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change

```
<% if current_user && !current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action) %>
        VOTED
      <%     else %>
     NOT VOTED

        <%= link_to "up", accept_improvement_action_path(improvement_action, type: "accept"), method: "post" %>
        <% end %>
```

to

```
<% if current_user && !current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action) %>
  NOT VOTED
  <%= link_to "up", accept_improvement_action_path(improvement_action, type: "accept"), method: "post" %>
<% end %>
```

first, and see if the up link show up or not

## update

apparently the railscast tutorial is outdated, the gem has been changed a lot. the reason it does not work anymore is because the database schema is changed completely, it is not using polymorphic anymore. the following code should fix your problem:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  has_reputation :accepts, source: {reputation: :accepts, of: :posts}, aggregated_by: :sum

  def voted_for?(post)
    Post.where(id: post.id).evaluated_by(:accepts, self)
  end

end
```

Comment: then what happens if you click the link?

Comment: it refresh the page and appear the same (only vote once, but cant hide the buttons after voted)

Comment: so the voting is done, and successfully updated in database right? it's just the `up` button is still showing right?

Comment: can you go to rails console, and find one `user` that has voted for a `improvement_action`. and call `user.voted_for?(improvement_action)`, see if it gives you true

Comment: it gives me false: >> `current_user.voted_for?(improvement_action)
=> false`

Comment: then can you update your question, and add your user Model code?

Comment: my user model is there

Comment: the gem version used in railscast is too old, the problem is at this line `has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source #accept answer (activerecord reputation-system gem)`

Comment: thanks, that didnt work, but I managed to solve using that way like this in the view: `<% ImprovementAction.evaluated_by(:accepts, current_user).each do |d| %>` , to find all votes by the current user.